# Summing values for every specific id and putting them into a groups

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task in Excel VBA, which I have never done before and I'm thinking if there is a simpler solution than mine.

I have a table in a sheet that looks like this:

| Name | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Tim | 2 |
| Jim | 3 |
| Sam | 2 |
| Jim | 1 |
| Sam | 2 |

And I want to get a number of unique names, that have 4 or more points. So I want to get a table that looks like this:

| Group | Number |
| --- | --- |
| < 4 | 1 |
| >= 4 | 2 |

In my real data I don't know how many unique names is in a set.

I thought of using Collection to solve this. I used it when I want to count number of unique names and it work fine, but now I want to get a sum of values in different columns. I will have a collection of sum of points as an Item and Name as a Key:

```
last_row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
On Error Resume Next
For i = 3 To last_row
    If coll.Contains(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
       a = coll.Item(CStr(.Cells(i, 1)))
       a = a + .Cells(i, 2)
       coll.Remove (CStr(.Cells(i, 1)))
       coll.Add a, CStr(Cells(i, 1))
    Else 
       coll.Add .Cells(i, 1), CStr(.Cells(i, 2))
    End If
Next
```

And then go through the collection and count how many names is in a specific group.

I think that is the only way to do this using collection, because I can't just add a number to the collection item, but maybe there is a some simpler way to to this?

Thanks a lot for every help!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a solution, based on the `=UNIQUE()`, `=SUMIF()` and `=COUNTIF()` functions, as explained here (I've put your data in cells A1:B6).

Cell D2 contains `=UNIQUE(A2:A6)` and automatically fills cells D2, D3 and D4.
Cell E2 contains `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,D2,$B$2:$B$6)`, E3 and E4 are dragged down.

Cell H2 contains `=COUNTIF(E2:E4,"<4")`.
Cell H3 contains `=COUNTIF(E2:E4,">=4")`.

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Its really nice sollution but I have a data with more than 110000 records and I don't want to make any tables during the process. Also it's important to make this as a VBA function becouse it will be generate with other tables in one Sub

Comment: @Aleksandra: you might get surprised how easy it might go: in order to create the second "table" (the one with the different names), I just wrote the formula `=UNIQUE(...)` in one cell (just try it). For the "table" in the "E" column, just write one formula (with `=SumIF(...)` and double-click on the right bottom corner of the cell and the next cells will be filled automatically. You can still do this in VBA, simply by recording your actions into a macro.

Answer (score 2):

For good measure, an answer you have **not** asked for but I wanted to give anyway in case you have access to the newest worksheet-functions:

[image]

```
=VSTACK({"Group","Number"},LET(X,4,Y,SUMIF(A2:A6,UNIQUE(A2:A6),B2:B6),HSTACK({"<";">="}&X,CHOOSE({1;2},SUM(--(Y<X)),SUM(--(Y>=X))))))
```

Where 'X' is the boundary you want to calculate. Consequently, if I had to change the 'X'-variable to hold '5', the output will look like:

[image]

Comment: Wow Sir, even the higher & lower bounds are created within the formula, this is amazing !

Comment: Sir, if possible could you shed some light on how `VSTACK()` is determining which is `Group` and which is `Number`. I am really surprised, this just blew me off!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, It's a matter of order. `{"Group","Number"}` is a horizontal array and it will be joined through `VSTACK()` which 2nd parameter is an array that on its own turn is joined through `HSTACK()` and was originally two vertical arrays.

Comment: Sir, just evaluated the formula, to make my self understand, honestly this is `EPIC` -- Thank you Sir, & everyone on `SO` amazing community! Sir, cant upvote, daily limit expired.