# How to summarize outcomes in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have a data set (a lot more columns involved than example) however, want to summarize outcomes on a separate sheet.

Well, can’t use pivots as I have to drop data in from an external source prior to the desired outcome.

Staff names will not be sorted also. There are 9 possible outcomes of 1 visit.

**DATA EXAMPLE**

```
Staff Name Status Of Visit
Staff 1    Successful 1 
Staff 1    Successful 2 
Staff 1    Unsuccessful 1
Staff 1    Unsuccessful 2
Staff 1    Closed 1
Staff 1    Successful 3
Staff 1    Successful 4
Staff 1    Successful 5
Staff 1    Closed 2
Staff 2    Closed 1
Staff 2    Successful 2
Staff 2    Closed 1
Staff 2    Unsuccessful 1
Staff 3    Successful 3
Staff 3    Successful 1
```

**Desired Output**

```
Staff Name Successful Unsuccessful Closed
Staff 1        5           2          2
Staff 2        1           1          1
Staff 3        2           0          0
```

and this is the formulas i have used for the staff names

```
=UNIQUE(staffnames)
```

and for the counts

```
=COUNTIFS(staffnames,$D3,B:B,E$2&"*")
```

but i assume there may be much better way to resolve this, can anyone help

Comment: If your `UNIQUE()` and `COUNTIFS()` give you the right result, it looks to me like there isn't a problem. Needing to import data from an external source shouldn't necessarily preclude the use of pivot tables though.

Comment: Assuming there may be better way to do this task, without using two formulas instead. may be by one formula,

Comment: You have two tasks: extracting staff names, then getting a count for each one. A formula for each task is the right approach. One improvement you could make is to create a table (select your data and then Insert > Table), then replace `staffnames` and `B:B` with structured references (`Table1[Staff Name]`, `Table1[Status Of Visit]`).

Comment: Like Delayed, In Progress, Waiting For Call, like these, yes I can't show the actual data for some reasons. I made up this one

Comment: in addition to @jsheeran 's comment (which I completely agree with), you may wish to replace the column headings with an array formula e.g. `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B:B))`

Comment: to make the whole thing fully dynamic, make your headings an array formula as per my comment above, then all the values of the table should be picked up by putting this array formula in the top right data cell; `=COUNTIFS(staffnames, D3#, B:B, E2# & "*")`.

Comment: I have searched on stackoverflow someone had created by one formula, I don't see that query, and it was expandable. It was just the same as mine, but I am not able to find that. the formula included the headers as well.

Comment: @JvdV like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71589837/18587694 is it possible

Comment: Probably @ZoeElizabeth, do you have the functions that are used in that linked answer?

Comment: Yes on my work computer it shows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=LET(X,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TEXTBEFORE(B2:B16," ",-1))),Y,UNIQUE(A2:A16),VSTACK(HSTACK(A1,X),HSTACK(Y,COUNTIFS(A2:A16,Y,B2:B16,X&"*"))))
```